# Just need some suggestions on improving knowledge of java 

Tags: java

I have been coding in java for a while now .... i want to continue in java and improve my coding abilities. I want some suggestions on -

1. any websites, blogs, to keep track of latest happenings in java like new coding techniques, standards, new java features, new APIs, basically anything new about java ..... (just for example sake Androidpolice keeps track all that is happening in android)
2. I have used a couple of classes from google guava libraries. are there any other such libraries which are helpful ?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Just wanna improve my java knowledge

Thanks

Comment: "Are there any such libraries..."? Only about a zillion, covering most any conceivable use. Are you talking about utility libraries, frameworks, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest you to participate actively in Stack Overflow. I improved a lot after joining SO. Better do lot of practice rather than reading. Create problems on your own and try to solve them. Practice makes man perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot recommend enough the **Effective Java** book by Joshua Bloch. The second (and most recent) edition assumes JSE6 hence recent (JSE7) features are not covered. But the content is impressive and certainly the kind of book I recommend developers who have moved beyond the basics.

Answer (score 2):

As sans481 told, you have to practices.
Try to create different application in Java.
& If error occurs StackOverflow is here to solve your problem.
First clear funda of Java if you are not aware with it then try it.

Good Luck....

Answer (score 1):

Try out some of the [TopCoder](http://topcoder.com) challenges. They may not improve your knowledge of the API but they will make you a better programmer and thinker, and you can use Java as an implementation language.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamagazine/index.html) is published on a bi-monthly basis in digital and mobile formats. It includes:

1. Profiles of innovative Java applications
2. Java technical how-to’s: Enterprise Java, New to Java, Rich Client, Polyglot Programming, and more
3. Java community news: Java User Groups, JCP standards, and more
4. Information about new Java books and conferences and events

Answer (score 1):

Similar to TopCoder, there is also CodeChef, Project Euler and SPOJ which will help you with algorithms and make you a better programmer; not to mention helping you learn to write working Java code quickly. It won't help you write large programs, or learn object oriented stuff, but I still think it helps.

Warning, CodeChef may make you want to learn C++ because it's much more popular for online coding competitions (due to speed and memory differences).